# Highlight entire line when there are matches

Tags: vim, line, match, highlight

Does anyone know how to highlight the entire line if there is or if there are matches after doing a search.

p.e. I do a search for  /user

Now I want to highlight the entire line if there are matches.

**EDIT**
I want to use the highlighting as in the search highlighting.
I don't want to use the highlighting groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
:let @/ = '.*\%(' . @/ . '\m\).*'
```

that should work for most regexp patterns (e.g. the bracketing takes care of `\|` branches). You could refine that to recognize `^` and `$`, and magic modifiers like `\V`.

Comment: thank you Ingo, that seems to work. What do you mean with refine that to recognize ^ and $? Yes I use also a lot of \V and \%V in regexes. Do you think your solution doesn't work with these?

Comment: ^ and $ are only special when they appear at the beginning / end (potentially within grouping parentheses), so `.*\(^...` will match a literal `^`, not the start of line any more. You'd have to check `@/` for these and adapt the concatenation.

Comment: `\V` changes the meaning of the trailing `.*`; it would need to be `\.\*` then. I've added a neutralizing `\m` to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. What would be your code if do a search then select a block of text and want to highlight only the entire lines with matches in this block of text? I tried to put `\%V(` before and  `\)` after your code but it doesn't work.

Comment: Uh, that's a different question. You have to `split(text, "\n")`, modify each part like in my answer, and then re-`join(text, "\n")`.

Comment: Split and rejoin? but...you're right, that is a different question. No matter. I'm already happy that your solution seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to highlighting the the lines might be using the `quickfix` list. For example doing following will put all lines matching the pattern `/user/` into the quickfix list for the current file (`%`).

```
:vimgrep /user/ %
```

You can display in a separate window the contents of the `quickfix` list by doing `:copen`. You can move between matching lines by `:cnext`, `:cprev`, and friends. I personally recommend Tim Pope's excellent [unimpaired.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin to provide some rather nice and natural feeling mappings like `[q` and `]q` to move through the `quickfix` list. You can also add a `g` flag to find multiple matches per line and add them to the `quickfix` list as well.

You may want to mapping to this  `vimgrep` command to make it a bit faster. I personally use the following in my `~/.vimrc`

```
nnoremap <leader>/ :vimgrep/<c-r>//g %<cr>:copen<cr>
```

A disadvantage to using `:vimgrep` command is that it needs a saved file, so unsaved buffers must be saved first. You can overcome this with using a combination of `:global` and `:cgetexpr` as shown below.

```
:cexpr []
:g//caddexpr expand("%").":".line(".").":".getline(".")
```

However maybe you really do just want to highlight the lines with a match instead of using the `quickfix` list. The I would suggest using `:match` like so

```
:match Search /.*user.*/
```

You can use whatever highlight group you want. I choose `Search` as it seemed appropriate. To turn off the highlighting just execute `:match` with out any arguments.

I personally prefer using `:vimgrep` and the `quickfix` list, but your needs may vary from mine.

For more help see:

```
:h quickfix
:h :vimgrep
:h :cnext
:h :cexpr
:h :caddexpr
:h :match
```

Comment: Tnx for the vimgrep info. I use it but it is not what I want. I want just to highlight the lines with a match. ... I once tried `/.*search-item.*` but it doesn't work in all cases p.e. it doesn't work with a lot of regex searches.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is acceptable for you:

first you need to define a highlight `group`: e.g. `userline`

```
:highlight userline ctermbg=darkred guibg=darkred
```

then you could:

```
:match userline /.*user.*/
```

all lines containing "user" would be highlighted.

Comment: thank you for replying Kent. No, that is not exactly what I want. I want to highlight the line as the search highlighting does. The reason is that I have a lot of scripts which with I can do operations on the search matches. I'm trying them to apply to the entire line. Hope I made myself clear. (I will add this to my question)